# Row bind csv files with different data types of a column

Tags: r, csv, bind

I have a folder containing multiple csv files. The data type of one of the column(suppose is "column1") in each csv may be different. I plan to use the following code to bind these csv files into a data.frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df_list<- list.files(path = ".\\csv_folder",pattern="*.csv",full.names=T )
df <- do.call(bind_rows, lapply(df_list,function(x) read_csv(x)))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't combine `column1` <double> and `column1` <character>.
```

How do I unify the data type of column1 and bind the csv files?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `do.call(rbind, ..`

Comment: `read.csv` is guessing your column types based on the data it finds in each file and is getting different answers for different files.  Use `colClasses` to override `read.csv`'s decisions.  You'll have to decide that's appropriate based on your data.  You haven't shared your data, so we can't help you.  Just beware of possible "odd" values - especially cpnventions used to record missing or unknown, in the csv files.

Comment: Thank you @markus, I appreciate it.  it is solved after using the `rbind`

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to insert a bit of your data in the question so we can see what you're dealing with. You can do so by using the following code

```
dput(head(mydata, x)) #where x is the number of rows you want for your sample, always try to keep it small
```

Without a sample of your data I can't see what the problem is, but it seems that the columns you're trying to bind are of different classes (*double* categories store numbers with two decimal digits, while a *character* variable it's stored as text).

Depending on what's best for you, you should try to change the class of one of those columns. Perhaps both are numeric but one of them is stored as a character column, in which case you should use

```
mydata$column1<-as.numeric(mydata$column1)
```

In case it's the other way round, you just gotta use `as.character` instead.

Hope it works!!